# GoogleAuthUtil cannot be resolved

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-authentication

I am using Google Play Service's Authorization with GoogleAuthUtil in my Android applcation. I did this part about 2 months back, its been working perfectly fine then onwards. Yesterday, I updated the SDK. Now I am getting this error in my application. It says "GoogleAuthUtil cannot be resolved".
Has anything changed in the updated SDK?
How can I solve this?

I am importing the following:

```
import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException.
```

I am getting

> com.google.android.gms.auth cannot be resolved.

Comment: I am importing the foll: import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException. I am getting  com.google.android.gms.auth cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you update any library make sure to first remove it from your references and again add it to your references. After that clean the project. Restart Eclipse if needed. And I feel then you are good to go!! :)

Comment: I am also having the same problem.can you pls explain how add and remove from referance.

Comment: I mean Just remove all the JAR references and add them again...In Android properties...Sry for late reply

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the `<uses-library>` tag from your AndroidManifest.xml and restart and clean everything. For sure it will start running.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Android Studio follow step below.

1. Open `SDK Manager` -> `SDK Tool` -> click on `Google Play` service and Apply
2. Open `Module Setting` or `Project Structure` -> on `Dependencies` tab click on `+` button -> select `1.Library Dependency` ->Select `play-services (...)` then click OK
3. Clean your project by `Build` -> `Clean Project`