# Android Studio - GoogleAuthUtil cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-authentication

I'm using Android Studio.

I need to use Google Accounts, but I'm getting an error.

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'GoogleAuthUtil'
```

I've imported the four main imports.

```
import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException;
```

Here's how I'm calling it.

```
final Account[] accounts = mAccountManager.getAccountsByType(GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
```

My AndroidManifest.xml has the following.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK" />
```

I selected Android 4.3 (Revision 18) Google APIs when starting my project.

Should I have the GooglePlayServices.jar in my libs folder? How do I do this in Android Studio?

I've tried restarting Android Studio, after trying to follow steps in this other question about Eclipse: [GoogleAuthUtil cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665255/googleauthutil-cannot-be-resolved).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a dup of a few other questions however:

Assure you have followed the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html), make sure you have installed the `Extras/Google Repository` from the SDK Manager and added the following dependency to your `<project>/<modulename>/build.gradle` file (**not** the root .gradle file):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.+'
 }
```

Next sync your project and Gradle files using [image: sync] then rebuild your project.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link. I only discovered the solution this morning, but hadn't had a chance to implement it, also the 3.1.+ is a nice addition.

Comment: The entire Play Services has to be included?  That is a huge library.

Comment: It has to be "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth" only!
hoss, please correct your response.

Comment: @YuriyChernyshov yes, why do we need all bundle. this answer must be updated.

Answer (score 19):

You need to add **play services auth** to your build.gradle's dependencies like this:
`com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0`

See more here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup